# LINQ and HTML Agility Pack filling the parsed HTML table data into a datatable

Tags: vb.net, linq, datatable, html-agility-pack

I am using the following query to parse html table data.

```
Dim q = From table In htmldoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table[@class='Seller']").Cast(Of HtmlNode)()
                    From row In table.SelectNodes("tr").Cast(Of HtmlNode)()
                    From header In row.SelectNodes("th").Cast(Of HtmlNode)()
                    From cell In row.SelectNodes("td").Cast(Of HtmlNode)()
               Select New With {Key .Table = table.Id, Key .CellText = cell.InnerText, Key .headerText = header.InnerText}
```

How can i use for each loops how can to fill this into a datatable?

I would create columns first using the header data then use a nested for each loop to fill the cell data in the table, but i am not sure how to, also any suggested changes on the above LINQ query?

**Note**: The html page contains only one table always.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the following `html`

```
Dim t = <table class='Seller' id='MyTable'>
            <tr>
                <th>FooColumn</th>
                <td>Foo</td>
                <td>Another Foo</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>BarColumn</th>
                <td>Bar</td>
                <td>Another Bar</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>ThirdColumn</th>
                <td>Third</td>
                <td>Another Third</td>
            </tr>
        </table>

Dim htmldoc = New HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument()
htmldoc.LoadHtml(t.ToString())
```

and your query

```
Dim q = From table In htmldoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table[@class='Seller']")
            From row In table.SelectNodes("tr")
                From header In row.SelectNodes("th")
                From cell In row.SelectNodes("td")
        Select New With {.Table = table.Id, .CellText = cell.InnerText, .headerText = header.InnerText}
```

you can use [`GroupBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.groupby.aspx) or [`ToLookup`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.tolookup.aspx) to group the objects by columns:

```
Dim grouped = q.ToLookup(Function(a) a.headerText)
```

and use this grouping to create a `DataTable` with the appropriate `DataColumn`s:

```
Dim dt = new DataTable()

For Each h in grouped.Select(Function(g) g.Key)
    dt.Columns.Add(h)
Next
```

Now, for filling the `DataTable`, you have to "rotate" the grouping, since each group contains the data for one column, but we want the data for each row. Let's use a little helper method

```
Function Rotate(Of T, TR)(source As IEnumerable(Of IEnumerable(Of T)), 
                          selector As Func(Of IEnumerable(Of T), IEnumerable(Of TR))) As IEnumerable(Of IEnumerable(Of TR))

    Dim result = new List(Of IEnumerable(Of TR))
    Dim enums = source.Select(Function(e) e.GetEnumerator()).ToArray()
    While enums.All(Function(e) e.MoveNext())
        result.Add(selector(enums.Select(Function(e) e.Current)).ToArray())
    End While

    Return result
End Function
```

to fill the `DataTable`.

```
For Each rrow in Rotate(grouped, Function(row) row.Select(Function(e) e.CellText))
    dt.Rows.Add(rrow.ToArray())
Next
```

And now the `DataTable` will look like this:

[image]